# Nodejs EventEmitter - Define scope for listener function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, eventemitter

I'd like to have something like this work:

```
var Events=require('events'),
    test=new Events.EventEmitter,
    scope={
        prop:true
    };

test.on('event',function() {
   console.log(this.prop===true);//would log true
});
test.emit.call(scope,'event');
```

But, unfortunately, the listener doesn't even get called. Is there any way to do this w/ EventEmitter? I could `Function.bind` to the listener, but, I'm really hoping `EventEmitter` has some special (or obvious ;) way to do this...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, because the `this` value in the listener is the event emitter object.

However what you can do is this

```
var scope = {
  ...
};
scope._events = test._events;
test.emit.call(scope, ...);
```

The reason your event handler did not get called is because all the handlers are stored in `._events` so if you copy `._events` over it should work.

Comment: Doh, seems so obvious now. Thanks for shining the light :).

Comment: Since the _events property created on objects extended from EventEmitter isn't part of its documented public interface, is this wise advice?

Comment: @RobRaisch No, but it's unlikely to change.

Comment: As of today, with Node 0.10.38, 0.12.4 and IO.JS 2.2.1, this approach still works without hiccup. Proven by time :) Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That won't work, and emit only has a convenient way to pass parameters, but none for setting `this`. It seems like you'll have to do the binding stuff yourself. However, you could just pass it as a parameter:

```
test.on('event',function(self) {
   console.log(self.prop===true);//would log true
});
test.emit('event', scope);
```

Comment: Like this for simplicity! However, if the emit is not under your control but the framework's that won't fix the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: All evidence to the contrary. 4 years later, the accepted answer still proves to be valid in every version of Node JS: 0.10.38, 0.12.4, IO.JS 2.2.1. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post when Google searching for a package in NPM which handles this:

```
var ScopedEventEmitter = require("scoped-event-emitter"),
    myScope = {},
    emitter = new ScopedEventEmitter(myScope);

emitter.on("foo", function() {
    assert(this === myScope);
});

emitter.emit("foo");
```

Full disclosure, this is a package I wrote.  I needed it so I could could have an object with an EventEmitter property which emits for the containing object.  NPM package page: https://www.npmjs.org/package/scoped-event-emitter

Comment: The accepted answer works perfectly, there is no need for a whole extra library :)

Comment: It's called code re-use.  The "whole extra library" is a 37 line Javascript file, but because it's a published package, you can use it in many projects without looking for that one project you added the accepted answer to.  In addition, the accepted answer did not exist when this was posted.