# Node.js event scope?

Tags: node.js, events, scope

I would like to use an event in node.js to execute some code; my question is, what is the scope of the invoked event code?  Specifically, does it share the scope of the event invoker, or is it "isolated"?  I know that I can pass parameters to the code invoked on the event to achieve a similar effect, but ideally I'd like to have the invoking scope available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you emit an event, you put it into a queue to be processed later by the node event system. Any variables from the scope where the event is emitted must be passed to `emit` as arguments. When node takes that event and triggers all bound callbacks, that happens under both a distinct "clean" scope and a distinct "clean" stack. (Side note, this is why stack traces in node can be a nuisance for debugging).

```
var events = require('events');

var myEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function closure1(word, number) {
  function closure2(animal, vegetable) {
    myEmitter.emit('hey', word, number, animal, vegetable, 43);
  }
  closure2("horse", "carrot");
}

myEmitter.on('hey', function (word, number, animal, vegetable, anotherNumber) {
  console.log('hey event fired with', word, number, animal, vegetable, anotherNumber);
});
closure1("table", 42);
```

When you run that, it will print "hey event fired with table 42 horse carrot 43".

[see the node.js docs on emitter.emit(event, [arg1], [arg2], [...]](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2)

Answer (score 4):

The event is tied to the scope of the invoker. i.e. an EventEmitter exported from a module, can only be used to listen for events emitted from that same EventEmitter.

[Nodejs EventEmitter - Define scope for listener function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005563/nodejs-eventemitter-define-scope-for-listener-function)